# Type only once when I hold a keyboard key in Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

Do we have any helper app or feature that disables continues typing on holding a key? Like when I hold 'g' key on my keyboard I don't want do see 'gggggg' but just one singe 'g'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Key Repeat and adjust the slider all the way down to "Off".